# Redirecting user to destination after they have successfully authenticated?

Tags: google-plus, google-authentication

When using the google+ authentication such as the example here: https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php#next_steps

I cannot seem to find how to redirect users after successful authentication to a landing page?

Does anyone know where this would be done? It looks like from this example is that redirection would be done client side once the token has been issued (and after storing a session variable)

Thanks

Comment: Which [sign-in flow](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#choosing_a_sign-in_flow) are you using?

Comment: Sorry, that would have helped! I am using one-time-code flow (client/server)... thanks

Comment: In that particular flow the redirect happens at `header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));` in step four. The user has finished authenticating and you can send them wherever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that particular flow the redirect happens at `header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));` in step four. The user has finished authenticating and you can send them wherever you want.